# How to display the first character from a WordPress title

Tags: php, wordpress, string, substr

In WordPress we use the code `<?php the_title(); ?>` for displaying the title of a post. Now, I want to display only the first letter of the title in a different place. How can I do that?

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<?php $my_title = the_title(); ?>

<?php
    $first_char = $my_title[0];
    echo $first_char;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Get the first character.
// $firstCharacter = $string[0];

$my_title = get_the_title();


// Get the first character using substr.
$firstCharacter = substr($my_title, 0, 1);
echo $firstCharacter;
```

The `the_title()` function will print it by default if the echo parameter is not set to false. `get_the_title()` will retrieve the title.

Comment: you're over-complicating simple thing. Not to mention OP's code should work

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski the_title() function will print it by default if echo parameter is not set to false. get_the_title() will retrieve the title.

Comment: I am talking about using `substr()` instrad `{x}` and 3 lines of code for literally oneliner.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski - I thought so too until I realized the `the_title()` is one of those wordpress functions that echos it's output instead of returning it.

Comment: @DebanjanB Updated the answer with desription

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
<?php echo get_the_title()[0]; ?>
```

As long as the title is not empty. Or:

```
 <?php echo substr(get_the_title(),0,1); ?>

 <?php echo preg_replace('/^(\w).+/','\1',get_the_title()); ?>

 <?php echo str_split(get_the_title())[0]; ?>

 <?php printf("%.1s", get_the_title()); ?> //echo sprintf
```

etc...

Or if you want to get complicated, you can use a "stream" yea!:

```
   $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');
   fputs($f, get_the_title());
   rewind($f);
   echo fgetc($f);
   fclose($f);
```

LOL - that was the hardest way I could think of, that does what it's supposed to and doesn't have any unnecessary steps (well, except `fclose`, but in this case we can recover the memory);

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eeb60859e5ab6c325a21b61b7dad07edf495dd87)

Comment: I like your first suggestion best and it will still work with empty title (in php7+) if you do: `get_the_title()[0] ?? ''`